# Angular JS- 1st Dropdown linked to 2nd linked to 3rd. Now I need selected data from 3rd drop down to display in another textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have posted the script and the controller. From one drop down I goto the second one and from the second to third. for example amazon's website where you got categories then to electronics and then to mobile.

Now I want to take that selected mobile and put it in another textarea.

I am building a sales management project and I am new to angular JS.

```
<!--This is the script--!> <script>
    function CategoryCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.categories = {'Electronics': {
    'Mobile': ['Samsung S6', 'Nokia 6', 'Motorola M2', 'Oneplus 3T'],
    'EarPhones': ['House of Marley H76', 'Sennheiser S789', 'Creative T242'],
    'Mouse': ['HP HP56', 'LG L11', 'Frontech F223']
    },
    'Clothing': {
    'T-Shirt': ['Levis T-Shirt 1231', 'PEPE T P6534', 'UCB T D7678'],
    'Shirt': ['Peter Englang P5466', 'Soldado S0944'],
    'Trouser': ['Vero Moda V6767', 'Arrow A6799']
    },
    'Books': {
    'Fiction': ['Red Serpant- Knox Vermount', 'Clove- Heather Tove', 'MajinBoo- Goku Gohan'],
    'Non-Fiction': ['Wings of Fire - APJ']
    }
    };
    }
    </script>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------- <!--This is the controller--!>
    <div ng-controller="CategoryCntrl">
    Category: 
    <select class="select form-control" id="category" ng-model="productTypes" ng-options="category for (category, productTypes) in categories">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>
    Product Type: <select class="select form-control" id="productT" ng-disabled="!productTypes" ng-model="products" ng-options="productT for (productT,product) in productTypes"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
     Product: <select class="select form-control" id="product" ng-disabled="!products || !productTypes" ng-model="product"><option value=''>Select</option> <option ng-repeat="product in products" value='{{product}}'>{{product}}</option></select>        
    </div>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <p>To be displayed here</p>
```

Comment: Please use simple language to describe your question.

Comment: I have edited into simple language. Thanks @JijoCleetus

Comment: i have added the answer. please check and let me know if there something else needs to be done.

Comment: @JijoCleetus My code is correct and was working earlier. That ng-app was added by me in another tag. MY question is what to do to display the last selected product into a text area

Comment: please use `<textarea ng-model="product"></textarea>`

Comment: this also works  `<p ng-bind="product"></p>`

Comment: This works when I put the textbox in the same controller, what if I were to use it outside the controller?

Comment: The scope is associated with the controller and if you use out side it won't work since scope is unavailable outside controller. Thats why we are using ng-controller to bound the data.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer it outside the controller like storing it or something else. Sorry for noob questions. Im learning.

Comment: You can try by firing an event during the last combo item change and store it in the localstorage but two way binding will not be available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed some areas in your code and seems to be working now.

**Angular Controller Code**

```
var app=angular.module('categoryApp',[]);
app.controller('categoryCntrl',['$scope',function($scope){

$scope.categories = {'Electronics': {
    'Mobile': ['Samsung S6', 'Nokia 6', 'Motorola M2', 'Oneplus 3T'],
    'EarPhones': ['House of Marley H76', 'Sennheiser S789', 'Creative T242'],
    'Mouse': ['HP HP56', 'LG L11', 'Frontech F223']
    },
    'Clothing': {
    'T-Shirt': ['Levis T-Shirt 1231', 'PEPE T P6534', 'UCB T D7678'],
    'Shirt': ['Peter Englang P5466', 'Soldado S0944'],
    'Trouser': ['Vero Moda V6767', 'Arrow A6799']
    },
    'Books': {
    'Fiction': ['Red Serpant- Knox Vermount', 'Clove- Heather Tove', 'MajinBoo- Goku Gohan'],
    'Non-Fiction': ['Wings of Fire - APJ']
    }
    };
 }]);
```

**Code for HTML template**

```
<div ng-app="categoryApp">
<div ng-controller="categoryCntrl">
    Category: 
    <select class="select form-control" id="category" ng-model="productTypes" ng-options="category for (category, productTypes) in categories">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>
    Product Type: <select class="select form-control" id="productT" ng-disabled="!productTypes" ng-model="products" ng-options="productT for (productT,product) in productTypes"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
     Product: <select class="select form-control" id="product" ng-disabled="!products || !productTypes" ng-model="product"><option value=''>Select</option> <option ng-repeat="product in products" value='{{product}}'>{{product}}</option></select>        
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: My code was working. I had added the ng-app another div. My question is to use the last product and display it into a textarea,

Comment: please use ` <textarea ng-model="product"></textarea>`